# How to use PHP FFMPEG to alter audio binary header bytes offset

Tags: go, audio, ffmpeg, binary, ffmpeg-php

I use the following method to create a WNB file that is flashable to my Electric Unicycle Ninebot Z10

First audacity to make the file raw pcm 16khz 16bit mono littleendian
Then wnb-slicer golang app to convert that raw file into wnb.

Today i did the same with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 -acodec pcm_s16le $1.raw
../wnb-slicer-master/wnb-slicer -file-name $1.raw
```

where $1 is the original file

About an hour ago i did the ffmpeg part with php-ffmpeg but i can't have golang run on a webserver.

So i thought if ffmpeg does bytes manipulation like the golang app does [here](https://github.com/berghauz/wnb-slicer/blob/master/wnb-slicer.go)

Thank you in advance!

p.s. this project will help all electric unicycle owners of the Z series wheels to change audio voices/sounds on their wheels!!

Comment: You don't need Go installed on your server to run wnb-slicer. Go is a compiled language. Build the program anywhere you like and copy the binary.

Comment: Yes i can do that, and i had done that, but i don't want to run shell_exec on the webserver cause i need to open php sessions and do the work, instead of like open a "screen" with name based on current date_time_seconds to be unique and the share the file into a temp folder based on that screen name from before and quote that link to the web output of the user. I'd like to run everything on php, i run php-ffmpeg with success, but still i cant splice :'(